# Requiring extra time beyond contact hours

Tags: masters

My question revolves around the legality of requiring students to attend an additional 2 hours of lecture time than the class is situated for. My understanding of the credit hours system is that a single credit hour is expected to be 50 minutes of contact time (ie, in-class time) per credit hour per week (in a 15 week semester, which this is). So, a 2-credit hour class would be expected to have 2 sessions of 50-minutes every week. However, in a class I am currently attending, my professor requires us to attend an additional lecture of a completely different class an additional 2 hours every week for no additional credit. We are required to attend, and every absence from this additional 2 hours, he has stated will result in a penalty of 1.5% off of our course grade for *each* absence. Essentially, the extra class he expects us to attend is the second class in a sequence of which we are currently enrolled for the first class. The idea is that he wants us to be better prepared for the class when we have to enroll in it next year/semester. However, I have a real problem with attending an extra class without credit, especially given that I had a scheduling conflict with these extra hours.
What legal recourse do I have, if any, to deal with this situation in the event that neither the professor nor the dean of my college will make any changes? What legal recourse do I have, if any, to deal with retribution if I file any kind of formal complaint about this issue?

Comment: Legal issues are beyond the scope of this site, and anyway we couldn't answer without knowing your jurisdiction.  Anyway, I doubt your odds are good via that route; most laws give universities a lot of latitude in setting their requirements.  However, I would say you have a very good chance of getting this changed by working within the university, by going through the department chair and/or dean.  Would you like to reframe your question to focus on those options?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law, but I will retract if it is edited to become on-topic.

Comment: "However, I have a real problem with attending an extra class without credit" - this sounds probably more absolute than you meant it, but I find the idea that the only motivation for attending a (not necessarily this particular) class is getting credit points for attendance really worrying.

Comment: The professor could be doing you a really big favor by getting you prepared for a really hard course. Perhaps not the best way... As for the "law" that a credit hour is 50 minutes - Ha ha ha - that makes me laugh. Go compare an upper English class credit hours with a Chemistry lab course...

Comment: The law.... Are you joking. Never in 100 years is this a law, anywhere. You should offer though to pay for the free extra tuition you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

In any situation like this, you should attempt to talk to the professor as soon as possible (without bringing up legal action...) and if needed escalate it to the department chair or ombudsman.

As far as legal advice, only a lawyer will be able to help with that, but I really wouldn't suggest jumping to such measures.. Professors are often reasonable people, as are chairs and deans, so hopefully someone can help you if you just walk through your issues with them.